# Terminal/Shell Script execution of iOS UIAutomation in Xcode 6

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode6, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Has anyone been able to successfully launch a UIAutomation .js script with instruments from the Terminal and/or a shell script yet?

This is the script I was using on Xcode 5 that was working fine:

```
instruments \
-w "167dd71e05a29312fe46ea66ec68be837ffcd127" \
-t  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate" \
 "/Users/automationken/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/7C2A685D-0CC9-40B4-A9B7-5C7C99DB93DC/something.app" \
 -e UIARESULTSPATH "/Users/automationken/source/something/ios_UIA/automation_results" \
 -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/automationken/source/something/ios_UIA/something.js"
```

Now I did notice that the automation template path has changed to:

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate"
```

And that the path of the new simulator is now:

> ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/

But I can't find an equivalent .app file anywhere in the sub directories beyond that. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?